# how to set mysql query in ascending order if default value is zero

Tags: mysql

I have one category table where i have used one field display order. But problem is that by default there will be zero value in this field. So now suppose if i set display order 1 and 2 in two records, then for all other records there will be zero value in display order.

Now if i display records as per display order then it shows zero value first. Actually i want that first those records should be display where i have set display order (i.e greater than zero). All zero values should be consider as last records.

How to write query for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may looking for case expression in ORDER BY Clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName  
ORDER BY CASE 
             WHEN ColName <> 0 THEN ColName 
             ELSE 9999
          END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Order by 
    case when `field` > 0 then `field` end ASC
  ,  `field` 
  , other columns
```

Use a case expression to ignore that default value.